# CSS Grid Column Flexible for Collapsible Content

Tags: css, css-grid

I am using CSS grid for my layout. 2 columns and three rows.
I would like the left column to be flexible so that the left column can contain a navigation bar that is collapsible, meaning that it opens/closes when I click a hamburger-menu button.
So far I have not found any examples.
Is it possible to make a column flexible from width 0 to any pixel width?

Comment: It is expected that you try to code this yourself first and if you get stuck you ask for help here providing the code you tried

Comment: You can't do that with a single grid container. What you are describing is **not a grid**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `min-content` in `grid-template-columns` property and set width of `sidebar` div, then if you change width of this element, `content` div should fill the empty space. Check snippet below.

```js
var collapsed = false

$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('.sidebar').css('width', !collapsed ? '100px' : '150px')
  collapsed = !collapsed
})
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar content";
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.sidebar { 
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
}

.content { 
  grid-area: content; 
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <button id='btn'>collapse</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```